# unable to send mail via php

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail

I am trying to send mail using php.And i am using WampServer.
so i tried the following code

```
ini_set("SMTP","smtp.gmail.com" );
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'person1@gmail.com');          
$to = "person2@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "person1@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$retval = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   if( $retval == true )  
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }
```

but it take more time to connect and says could not connect with localhost.
Please help me in solving the problem

Comment: Are you sure the port is open or usable?

Comment: i used netstat -an and could not see port no 465.this does means it is blocked?

Comment: try to add port 465 for outbound permissions of your firewall if it's enabled.

Comment: but i have totally disabled the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this configuration:

http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/

this might help.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on something similar using XAMP and was able to send emails through [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) PHP library.

There is a variety of examples that can be found in `PHPMailer/examples/` that can be quite helpful. Below is a sample code that can be used to send an email using PHPMailer.

> Note: it requires downloading the library files and adjusting the path
> to the `require` or `use` files which are Exception, PHPMailer, and
> SMTP.
> Also, This implementation requires the sender's username and password to send the email not efficient for contact forms.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet =  "utf-8";
$mail->IsSMTP();
// enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  

$mail->Username = "Email to Send From"; // GMAIL username

$mail->Password = "#########"; // GMAIL password
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port = "465"; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

$mail->From= $emailFrom;
$mail->FromName='SenderName';
$mail->AddAddress($emailTo, $name);
$mail->Subject  =  'EMAIL SUBJECT';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body    = "

    Dear ".$name.", <br><br>

    Some Text/Message Content. <br><br>

    Regards";

// Temporary fix, remove if SSL available
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
)
);

try {
$mail->Send();

  // Sent Successfully
  
}catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Mail Error - >".$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to send mail from your localhost (Your PC) I guess It's not setup to send mail. Move the script to a production server and it will work